# gaussdb: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: open-gauss

I am trying to install openGauss by compile source code and my complie is all good but when I try to `sudo make install` it happens that error.How can I fix this problem?

Here is my `.bashrc` file:

```
export CODE_BASE=/home/dblab/opengauss-compile/openGauss-server-v3.0.0 # Path of
export BINARYLIBS=$CODE_BASE/../binarylibs-v3.0.0
export GAUSSHOME=$CODE_BASE/dest
export GCC_PATH=$BINARYLIBS/buildtools/centos7.6_x86_64/gcc7.3
export CC=$GCC_PATH/gcc/bin/gcc
export CXX=$GCC_PATH/gcc/bin/g++
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$GAUSSHOME/lib:$GCC_PATH/gcc/lib64:$GCC_PATH/isl/lib:$GCC_PATH/mpc/lib/:$GCC_PATH/mpfr/lib/:$GCC_PATH/gmp/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=$GAUSSHOME/bin:$GCC_PATH/gcc/bin:$PATH
```

I tried to install openssl-1.1g and I expected that it may works.